# A program for inverting strings in c using pointers and bubble sort

Tags: arrays, c, string, sorting

I have to write a program that takes a string input and inverts it, so basically reverses the text.
I also wanted to try and reuse one of my codes that had bubble sort and thought it could work.

So this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
int n;
char arr[n];
printf("Input length:\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
printf("Input string:\n");
scanf("%s",&arr);
bsort(arr);
printf("%s",arr);



}


void swap(char *x,char *y){
char temp=*x;
*x=*y;
*y=temp;
}

void bsort(char *arr, int n){
int i, j;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(&arr[j]<&arr[j+1]){
            swap(arr[j],arr[j+1]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I don't know if I messed up data types, operators, or the functions altogether.
When I run the program, there's nothing printed out.
I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You call `bsort` from `main` before it is either declared or defined. And, even then, you pass it **one** argument whereas the defintion requires **two** arguments.

Comment: `char arr[n];` uses an uninitialised value of 'n'... Your compiler must be spewing errors and warnings... Try to figure out those for yourself... (PS: reversing the elements of an array has nothing to do with sorting... 'swapping' perhaps, but 'sorting', no...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


void reverseString(char* str)
{
    int l, i;
    char *beginPtr, *endPtr, ch;

    // Get the length of the string using this func instead of aking input
    l = strlen(str);

    // Setting the beginPtr
    // to start of string
    beginPtr = str;

    //Setting the endPtr the end of
    //the string
    endPtr = str + l - 1;
    //basically we add the (len-1)
    
    // Swap the char from start and end
    // index using beginPtr and endPtr
    for (i = 0; i < (l - 1) / 2; i++) {

        // swap character
        ch = *endPtr;
        *endPtr = *beginPtr;
        *beginPtr = ch;

        // update pointers positions
        beginPtr++;
        endPtr--;
    }
}

// Driver code
int main()
{

    // Get the string
    
    char str[100];
    printf("Enter a string: ");

    scanf("%s",&str);

    // Reverse the string
    reverseString(str);

    // Print the result
    printf("Reverse of the string: %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to explain this code using comments
if u dont wanna use string.h then u can ask input for length of the string

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot more sense. I'm still kinda disappointed that mine doesn't really work, but i'll learn from yours and try fixing mine